# Is adding / removing from classlist "ok" in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a `directive` that enables drag and drop for elements. While I am dragging I am giving the dragged element and the elements I am dragging over some classes. Right now I am doing something like this

```
onDragStart(event: DragEvent) {
    event.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", this.article.id.toString());
    this.el.classList.add(this.draggedItemClass);
}
```

`this.el` is the native element that I am dragging. I.e. I am writing a css class from my `Component` using JavaScript. I found similar code in some ng library but it feels like I am doing something wrong and should not write css-classes with JavaScript and rather should do this via my template. So my question is is adding / removing from classlist "ok" in Angular 2 or should I go via the template in some way (probably using my data as a basis)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a directive, you can always use @HostAttribute binding. And that is the best practice for sure.
Example:
`@HostBinding('class.someClass') someField: boolean = false;`
so in that onDragStart, you will just do `someField = true`

This is cleanest and best soulution.

P.S. Your solution is not that bad because you let Angular to give you access to the element which is good, and you are not selecting it manually from the document, but anyway, the above mentioned solution is way better